# Magento 2.1 Need to show popup in admin grid action with Ui Component

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have added following code. but seems it's not working

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item[AlertInterface::ID])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                         'view' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('adminhtml/*/preview', ['id' => $item['id']]),
                            'popup' => true,
                            'target' => '_blank',
                            'label' => __('Preview')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```